# Java deflate response

Tags: java, servlets, response, servlet-filters, deflate

Hello all
I want to make a filter for tomcat to deflate all responces of certain MIME type.
Any guidelines?

```
...
 String ae = request.getHeader("accept-encoding");
        if (ae != null && ae.indexOf("deflate") != -1) {
            deflate response...?????
        }
chain.doFilter(request, res);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that in a homebrewed `Filter`. Configure it at server level. In case of for example Apache Tomcat, just add `compression="on"` to `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`. It will GZIP responses whenever client accepts it (GZIP is based on deflate and practically every client supports it whenever deflate is supported).

```
<Connector compression="on">
```

That's all. You can if necessary configure mime types by `compressableMimeType` attribute.

#### See also:

- [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference - The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: Thanks.I have a servlet that responds with json and that responce is not zipped(on a particular request as i noted before the responce was and is the same size) as i saw with firebug.Any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. You already figured that you just have to add `application/json` to `compressableMimeType` attribute, right?