# convert this Apache Rewrite rule to tuckey URLRewriteRule

Tags: java, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Can tuckey.org [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) use for make browser know about compress css file like css.gz and run it well.

Actually, I have used this Apache Rewrite rule to do it in PHP, and run it well

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
AddType application/x-javascript .gz
AddType text/css .gz
```

and can that rule comvert to tuckey.or [URLRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) ???

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaken, this has nothing to do with mod_rewrite. You actually have 2 unrelated parts in your configuration:

- one using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) directives, but without a `RewriteRule`, so it's incomplete and useless (cf. the documentation for [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)):

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*
  ```
- and one using [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html) directives (incorrectly, as it tries to set 2 types for the same `.gz` extension):

  ```
  AddEncoding x-gzip .gz
  AddType application/x-javascript .gz
  AddType text/css .gz
  ```

So no, you can't use `URLRewriteFilter` to do that as it's not related to rewriting URLs, and you really want to use [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) in your Apache configuration instead. For the Java equivalent, see [Java deflate response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813281/java-deflate-response) for example.